# Official android.location.Location.getBearing() documentation out of sync with Android project source code

Tags: android, geolocation

The [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/03d7a23d36a0ba278c7aa6af310c72a20f87fa24/location/java/android/location/Location.java#765) for `getBearing()` method states:

```
    /**
     * Get the bearing, in degrees.
     *
     * <p>Bearing is the horizontal direction of travel of this device,
     * and is not related to the device orientation. It is guaranteed to
     * be in the range (0.0, 360.0] if the device has a bearing.
     *
     * <p>If this location does not have a bearing then 0.0 is returned.
     */
```

But the [official Android docs for that class](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/Location#getBearing()) have the range defined as:

```
The bearing is guaranteed to be in the range [0, 360).
```

which clearly differs in whether 0 or 360 is valid or invalid, i.e. the invalid bearing of 0.0 which indicates the Location does not have a bearing, is valid according to the developer portal docs.

The weird thing the source for this class has basically stayed the same for years and the documentation for it in developer portal has changed only recently to this.

If there is a place where I could report this issue to the maintainers of the developer portal, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is generated from the source code.  So I would expect the code to be correct, and the documentation just to need to be re uploaded.  The difference between these two can be solved by using `getBearing()%360.0f`, which will force it into [0,360.0)

Comment: That is true, but according to the source code, 0 means that the Location does not have a bearing, so the conversion does not help here.

Comment: @juke I would suspect that's the reason for the change-  to reserve a value for UNKNOWN.  Notice that the docs do not reserve any value for that, but instruct you to call hasBearing instead.  Although its also possible that it always returned 0 for unknown and this is correcting the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it: 360 degrees are a full turn. So 0° is equal to 360° degrees after normalization.
the desync is propably because of a different version, cause the official doku is also javadoc.